# Install Python packages in VOLTTRON

Tags: python-2.7, volttron

How can I install Python packages in VOLTTRON Python interpreter?
Which folders does VOLTTRON python interpreter check for Python packages?

Answer (score 1):

VOLTTRON uses a virtual environment to isolate itself from the system python.  Once activated VOLTTRON keeps its created packages in $VOLTTRON_HOME/packaged.

If you are asking about the regular python packages aka things that are installed from pypy you can install using pip install  and those are in the env/lib/python2.7 folder under the volttron repository.

Comment: Thank you very much, pip install in the env/lib/python2.7 folder would work.